# Uppercase letter using C++ preprocessor (x -> getX/setX)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I would like to define some properties like:

```
#define property(T, x) T x; T get ## x (); void set ## x (T value);

class foo { 
public: 
  property(int, count);
  property(float, size);
}
```

but I would like methods to be called getCount/setCount and not getcount/setcount.

Comment: That's not possible. You could change your macro though: `property(int, count, Count)` (or `property(int, c, C, ount)` to minimize duplication (don't do it, it was a joke))

Comment: This isn't Java.  In accepted C++ style, the functions should be named `get_x()` and `set_x()` (except that the length or count should be named `size()` and `resize()`).

Comment: If - as your macro suggests - your variable is public, why bother with accessors?

Comment: @BenVoigt, it's not an standard. Although I personally prefer `_`, camelCase or `_` is the programmers choice of style.

Comment: This is not actual implementation, this is just a minimal example of what I would like to achieve. I'm just interested in making one letter uppercase.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Actually, it is standard.  The Standard uses `words_separated_by_underscores` exclusively, never `camelCase`.  But not all programmers follow the Standard's style.

Comment: The short answer is that it's just not supported. The preprocessor doesn't include any ability to change the case of a letter in an identifier. In any case, you're chasing a dead-end. To paraphrase Niklaus Wirth: "if you think you need properties, what you really need is to learn how to program."

Comment: @BenVoigt: The good thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from... in my book, the standard is what the majority of people uses, not what some committee or so decided to use (ask anybody working on HTML engines or C++ source code parsers about this to hear interesting anecdotes).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: There's only one C++ standard (well, three versions of it, but they all use the same spelling)

Comment: Please don't try to do properties in C++. You will regret it. If you think you need properties, go back to C# or Java.

Comment: what about qt and qml? there're properties everywhere...

Answer (score 7):

As the comment says, you cannot do that. Preprocessor doesn't do those kind of things.

So either you follow what @Shahbaz said in the very first comment, or do something like this which gives you get and set of `get_count` and `set_count` form.

```
#define property(T, x) private : T m_## x; \
public : T get_## x () { return m_## x;} \
void set_## x (T value) { m_## x = value; }

class foo { 
public: 
  property(int, count);
  property(float, size);
};

int main() {
        foo f;
        f.set_count(10);
        std::cout << f.get_count() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

[Quick demo at ideone](http://ideone.com/glvrU)

Note that the variable is declared in the `private` section and its name is `m_count`, and the functions are *defined* (not only *declared*) in the `public` section.

Or, you could pass `Count` instead of `count` in the macro as:

```
 property(int, Count);
```

If you do so, then you could create the variable as `m_Count` and functions as `getCount` and `setCount`. That is closest to what you want.

Answer (score 3):

No way (that I know of) to do this using the C pre-processor. I'd suggest as a compromise, you go for an underscore and use `get_count()` which is easily read. Other alternatives:

- If you really want to stick with a pre-processor you could investigate using `m4` as a first step. It's definitely possible with `m4` as I've done something very similar. That said, this seems a bit complicated for what you want to achieve.
- Add an extra parameter so you get `#define property(T, x, name)` which allows you to specify the name seperately. It's more flexible but again probably not what you want.
- If it's really just the legwork of creating the accessors / mutators, there are plenty of IDEs and code generators that will do it for you or you could write some shell / Python / Perl to knock this out as a one off very easily.

Two final observations: Although it might seem more efficient to write it this way, remember that anyone maintaining your code may well do a search for `setCount()` and not find it which will waste time until they puzzle out what you've done. I.e. from a code maintennce perspective, **keep it simple**. Secondly, it's good practice to denote macros in upper case, since that way they are easily identified as such. Again this really helps when you're maintaining code.